# Minimal spanning tree (adjacency matrix) in java

Tags: java, algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I have a problem that I am really struggling with. I have a set villages with weighed edges and I need to create a minimum spanning tree to find the shortest way.I have found the shortest path for the villages according to the weight,I really have no idea what to do
How can i implement this with adjacency matrix ? i will appreciate any help :)
-10 villages(Nodes)

Comment: Check out [Kruskal's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm); it's a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout dijkstra or A+ algorithm to find shortest path with weighted edges. A* additionally uses a metric (heuristice) function which it makes faster to Dijkstra.

Comment: Just googled Dijkstra and found this: http://www.vogella.com/articles/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html. It is a well know algorithm. I think it's no problem to find a complete documentation or any kind of tutorial. In any case it is very interesting to learn anything about search algorithms.

Comment: There is another StackOverflow Issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7197418/where-can-i-get-a-java-implementation-of-dijkstras-algorithm